# How to create background css div/rounded corners?

Tags: html, css

How can I create the following html/css style (rounded corners, basic background-color) highlighted in red box:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `border-radius` CSS property to create rounded borders:

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px;    /* Firefox 3.6-, removed in Firefox 13 */
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* Safari 4-, Chrome 3- */
border-radius: 5px;     /* Firefox 4+, Safari 5+, Chrome 4+, Opera 10.5+, IE9+ */
```

You can leave out the prefixes, because Firefox 3.6 or old webkit browsers are almost extinct.

Although it's possible to get rounded corners in OldIE (IE8-) using divs+images or [PIE.htc](http://css3pie.com/), I recommend against it: PIE is not very reliable, and adding several HTML hacks just to get something to work in old IE is a waste.

See also: **[MDN: `border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius)**.

Comment: Realistically, you only need `border-radius: 5px`. Current versions of all browsers that support `border-radius` support it without the vendor prefix, and have done for a while.

Comment: In FireFox 3.6, which is still widely used, the `-moz-` prefix is still necessary. Many users don't have the latest version of the browser.

Comment: You're correct about `-moz-`, I didn't think carefully enough.